# How can I make AutoHotkey scripts work on computers without AutoHotkey installed?

Tags: autohotkey

Normally to open a `.ahk` file you will need to have installed AutoHotkey and then it will appear in the taskbar.

However recently I found a `.exe` file that was actually an auto hotkey script and it added the script to the taskbar when I opened it. I'm assuming that this did not need AutoHotkey installed.

How would I go about making a `.exe` file (or some other method) in order to run my script on computers that do not have AutoHotkey installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoHotKey includes a script compiler with it's installer.

There are a few ways to use the script compiler:

- Run the `convert .ahk to .exe` Start Menu item under the AutoHotKey folder.
- Right Click in Explorer any `.ahk` file and select `Compile Script`. This method is only available if you selected the compiler during installation.
- Use the Command Line:

> `Ahk2Exe.exe /in MyScript.ahk [/out MyScript.exe] [/icon MyIcon.ico] [/bin AutoHotkeySC.bin] [/mpress 0or1]`

Example:

> `Ahk2Exe.exe /in "MyScript.ahk" /icon "MyIcon.ico"`

Source: http://ahkscript.org/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe

Comment: SciTE4AutoHotkey [http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/] is also a convenient development environment that has compile options available within the IDE.